# Google Apps Script how to call external .gs

Tags: google-apps-script

Starting this question from scratch with a better explanation:

I have two scripts - one is the primary file and the second is basically a library I want "copied" to the primary. Here is my current code:

Code.gs

```
function doGet(){return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(0)}
function nP(page){var pageOutput=HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(page).getContent();return pageOutput}
```

0.html

```
<body>First Page<button id="p2">Second Page</button></body>
<script>document.getElementById("p2").onclick=function(){google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(cP).nP(1)}</script>
```

1.html

```
<body>First Page<button id="p1">First Page</button></body>
<script>document.getElementById("p1").onclick=function(){google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(cP).nP(0)}</script>
```

My goal is to have an external .gs file with the nP function that I will be able to use in other web apps (this being a start, having this ability would be extremely useful with other functions also). I'm looking for an option similar to HTML's  where it acts like it's written in the file if possible for simplicity. Or I can use the library option if it does in fact work, I've just ran into issues where it says the function doesn't exist, invalid variable or invalid return.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way in which you can call external .gs files and it will work just like that external script is written in your script's another .gs file.

For that, you will have to use `UrlFetchApp.fetch(String url)` method.

What to pass in **String url**? -> External script's deployed as web app URL. Yes, you will have to deploy other .gs file as web app and when you update it, it shows an URL, copy it and use it in your **fetch** method.

To pass values to external .gs file, you can use **?xyz=abc** and then in that external script, use `doGet(e)` and then `e.parameter.xyz;`

Just make sure the files which are getting accessed by the script are available to each script properly.

Refer this: [UrlFetchApp method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app)

Answer (score 0):

The way to call a code in external .gs files is by adding the project that contains them as a library.

As alternative you could use

- [Google Apps Script Execution API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/rest/api)
- Publish your other Google Apps Script as a [web app](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)